# How to install a DataTables Editor with an Authentication Token to Visual Studio 2019 via NPM

Tags: npm, datatable, npm-install, jquery-datatables-editor, visual-studio-package

I have an Authentication Token that I need to use as a license for DataTables Editor. I was told that I can only use it if I install an Editor via NPM. I am using Visual Studio 2019.

editor.datatables website has instructions on how to do NPM installation on it. But it wasn't detailed enough for me to follow it.
I found similar solutions here on stackoverflow, but none of them were about the package I need.
This is the instructions from editor.datatables website that I wasn't able to run successfully:
[image]
[image]